# How to DRY my SASS

Tags: sass

I'm new to SASS and I'm trying to DRY this one:

```
nav {
  ul {
    li a:hover {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #e12a1a;
    }
    li a.active {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #e12a1a;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
nav ul li a {
  &:hover, &.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e12a1a;
  }
}
```

Which will output:

```
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e12a1a;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks @Josh Crozier